Constrained random sine in R: how can I meet all the restrictions?
I need some help with my R code.
I try to generate a constrained random sine function for a biological experiment. The sine refers to a daily variable temperature, divided in 24 breaks (one per hour) with the first 12 hours representing day time (category = D) and the second 12 hours representing night time (category = N). I replicated this pattern 30 times for 30 days in a month.
sine_month <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 24), 30),
           time = rep(format(seq(from = as.POSIXct("00:00", format="%H:%M"), 
                                               by = "1 hour", 
                                               length.out = 24), 
                                           format = "%H:%M"), 30),
           sin_value = rep(sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 24)), 30), 
           category = rep(ifelse(sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 24)) < 0, 'N', 'D'), 30),
           day = rep(1:30, each = 24))

I added 10 to each sin_value to get a mean temperature of 10 degrees.
sine_10d <- sine_month %>%
  mutate(sin_value = sin_value+10)

From there I need to modify the sin_value column meeting some conditions, and I didn't succeed.
Here are the conditions:

For each point in category = D, add a random value in [0.1;3.5]
For each point in category = N, add a random value in [-3.5;-0.1]
Maximum sin_value = 13.5
Minimum sin_value = 6.5
Exactly 10 sin_value in category = D = 13.5
Exactly 10 sin_value in category = N = 6.5
The average value of each day = 10

I tried to create functions and loops but I'm stuck with the max and min condition, and with the exactly 10 values condition.
If someone know how could I get to this, please share it with me.
Regards,
Jeremy

A couple hints:   foo[foo>X] <- X  ;    index_D <- sample(1:12, 10) ; D[index_D] <- 13.5
